# how to read ellipses data in java or using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to read data which ends with the ellipses(`...`) in java and selenium.
I have tried with the option as `gettext().split(",")[0]`. Each time the data length gets differently some times data will display with `","` or some time data will display `"Name..."` in this situation it is difficult to get to know where the comma `","` ends. When hover the mouse on the text will get display the full data on the tooltip. Please help how to handle it.

Comment: not enough info, do you have screenshots?

Comment: shows us an example of your input you are expecting

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, the ellipsis is used to limit the amount of text that is shown for large texts.  All of the data is there but it won't show on the screen.  If you want to see more of the long text, you would need to break it down into smaller Strings or write it out to a file.

Comment: Thank you for ur replay. As request please find the details: as the string name length cross 20 then the content will show in ellipses (...) and if hover the mouse then the full length of data will be visible. For me i need to get the full length if it contains ellipses. I need to handle in selenium test with help of java.

Comment: Can any one help me in this issue get data from ellipses using java selenium